# Finding the error interpolating function.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

While looking at the video I've linked at the end of this question about the error formula for interpolating functions, I got confused at the following example  $$if n=1, x_0 =a, x_1 =b , b>a  $$ find an upper bound for the error. Recall $ e(x) = ((f^{n+1}(c))/(n+1)!)(x-x_0)...(x-x_n) $ The step I'm confused is the following:$$\max_{a<=x<=b}|(x-a)(x-b)|= ...=(b-a)^2/4$$
How is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need to solve *((x-a)*(x-b))' = 0* and you'll get *x=(a+b)/2* and function value *-(b−a)(b-a)/4*